# Cannot determine the field name in a magento filter query

Tags: magento, where-clause, addattribute

I'm having trouble with using an OR filter in a Magento query. This is what i used:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter(
                            array(
                               array('attribute'=>'status','eq'=>'pending'), 
                               array('attribute'=>'created_at', 'from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$finishDate)
                            )
     );
```

I want the following WHERE statement: `WHERE 'status' = 'pending' OR (created_at < $startDate AND created_at > $finishDate)`
but i get the following error message

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Cannot determine the field name.' in /home/content/r/o/n/ronakkaria/html/magento/app/Mage.php:563 
 Stack trace: 
 #0 /home/content/r/o/n/ronakkaria/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php(52): Mage::throwException('Cannot determin...') 
 #1 /home/content/r/o/n/ronakkaria/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php(80): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract->_attributeToField(Array) 
 #2 /home/content/r/o/n/ronakkaria/html/new/admin/magentoInvoice/getInvocieList.php(43): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter(Array) 
 #3 {main} thrown in /home/content/r/o/n/ronakkaria/html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 563
```

I am currently using version 1.6-2rc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik you cannot use `addAttributeToFilter()` to `OR` two attributes for the `sales/order` model.

Use `addAttributeToSearchFilter()` instead:

```
$startDate = '2011-01-01';
$finishDate = '2011-01-31';

var_dump(
    Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSearchFilter(
       array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'eq' => 'pending'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'created_at',
                'from' => $startDate,
                'to' => $finishDate
            )
       )
    )
    ->getSelectSql(true)
);
```

This will create a WHERE clause of:

```
WHERE 
    (status = 'pending') OR 
    (created_at >= '2011-01-01' AND created_at <= '2011-01-31')
```

Comment: Btw, the condition you mention below the first code part of your question makes no sense (at least to me). Since it means "include orders which were created both, *before* `$startDate` AND *after* `$finishDate` at the same time", which most likely never will happen (except you're going to use weird values^^). I assume this was just a typo, right?